# React build taking too long to complete with message "95% emitting CopyPlugin" - How to debug npm build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, copy-webpack-plugin

Build taking too long to complete in my local system. It showing the message  "95% emitting CopyPlugin" when I run "npm start" and waits for 7 or  8 hours to complete, even same thing happens when I make code changes if code change is one line or a class name change it again takes a long time to complete.

```
{
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --watch --env.buildFlavor development --mode development",
}
```

it working fine with my previous system with almost the same configuration as the new machine.

**webpack**: ^4.41.2"

**OS**: windows 10

Is there any solution to this problem?

What is the best way to debug and find out what is causing this issue?

Comment: Did you exclude node_modules in webpack rule?

Comment: In webpackconfig file I find  this code "exclude: /node_modules|src[\\\/]third-party/," so I think it is exluded node_module in webpack rule @KostyaTresko

Comment: Can you create a minimal public project with the same problem?

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/speed-measure-webpack-plugin to see what is taking too long.

Comment: You should post webpack config file. This does not give much to work with. Also add --verbose option to your command so we can see more details.